# Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, operator-theory

Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. Why? This is just a Laplace operator with derivative boundaries.

```
T = L\r;

L=

-1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -2     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1     1
```

[image: aa]

Comment: The columns add to zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown what should I do to change?

Comment: The pure Neumann Laplace operator has constants (and only constants) in its kernel. So you can uniquely choose a solution by adding an equation that sets one of the values equal to a given constant. The resulting system of $n+1$ equations will have a unique solution provided a "compatibility condition" is satisfied (which says the total flux from boundary conditions and forcing is zero).